# How to call DB2 stored procedure in Zend Framework 2 placed in IBM i

Tags: zend-framework2, db2, ibm-midrange

I have configured Zend Framework2 in my local machine (ubuntu 14.04 LTS) with IMB_db2 driver as below.

*global.php*

```
$conn_string = "DATABASE='';HOSTNAME='xxx';PORT='xxx';PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID='xxx';PWD='xxx'";

return array(
    'db' => array(
        'driver' => 'ibmdb2',
        'database' => $conn_string,
        'username' => '',
        'password' => '',
        'hostname' => '',
        'port' => '',
        'driver_options' => array(
            'DB2_ATTR_CASE' => DB2_CASE_LOWER
        ),
        'platform_options' => array(
            'quote_identifiers' => false
        )
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory'),
    ),
);
```

*local.php*

```
return array('db' => array('username' => 'xxx','password' => 'xxx',));
```

Using zend adapter I have called the stored procedure placed in a iseries box as below.

```
$sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
$this->adapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$stmt = db2_prepare($this->adapter, 'Call <Procedure name>("xxx","xxx","?","?")');
if (!$stmt) {
    die('Preparing Statement failed.' . db2_stmt_error());
}
```

From the above snippet I am getting 'Preparing Statement failed.' with out any error message.

When I print $this->adapter, it is giving connection object.

Can any one help me on this, please?

Comment: In SQL double quotes are used for identifiers; string literals must be enclosed in single quotes. Parameter markers do not need quotes.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is while preparing the statement, it is saying 'Warning: db2_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given'.    I want connection resource from the Adapter object. Please help me...